# Nodejs Mysql asynchronous

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to return my users list from my Mysql database through this endpoint.

The problem is that it return "undefined".

Do you know how to solv this?

Thx in advance :)

```html
app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
  users = await query_my_users_from_db()
  // Got "users = undefined" here
  console.log(users)
  return JSON.stringify(users)
})

async function query_my_users_from_db() {
  var users = await db.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
    users = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))
    return users
  })
}
```

Comment: It seems you are mixing two different concepts, one is using callbacks, and the second promises, what was your intention?
You can read about the difference between those two mechanisms here for example
https://dev.to/neisha1618/callbacks-vs-promises-4mi1

Answer (score 0):

Since `db.query` is callback based, you should change your code into:

```
function query_my_users_from_db(callback) {
   db.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", callback)
}
```

**remove all the async\await since you are not using any promises!**

then define your callback

```
const usersHandler = (err, result) => {
 ... do what you want with your users ...
}
```

and use it like this:

```
query_my_users_from_db(usersHandler)
```

Another option is to use some promise-based wrapper package for MySQL, there is plenty or use node `util.promisify()` (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-util-promisify-method/) and then use async\await and remove the callback altogether.

Hope that it helps

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it's working like a charm.

```
db.promise = (sql, params) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(sql, params, (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(new Error())
          } else {
            resolve(result)
          }
        })
      })
    }

    async function connection(query) {
      const result = await db.promise(query)
      return result
    }

    app.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
      users = await connection("SELECT * FROM `users`")
      return users
    })
```

Comment: A small tip: [`const { promisify } = require('util');`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal) (or `import { promisify } from 'util';`) turns a function that takes a callback into a Promise-based one: `const query = promisify(db.query).bind(db);` + `const users = await query('SELECT * FROM users');` - the `.bind()` is needed, otherwise the "`this`" will be wrong. The `mysql2` NPM package [is already Promise-based](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/6d90788d0d91a9f8fab3125b42805c40f8ad1d74/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md#es7-async-await).